# Add element to existing group using svg.js

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I have a loaded svg map, and then I create some paths that I want to be added inside a group of the loaded SVG, but I cant.

Here I load my map

```
var mapa = SVG('map').size('100%', '100%');

var mapLoad = new XMLHttpRequest();
mapLoad.open('GET', 'img/my_map.svg', true);
mapLoad.send();
mapLoad.onload = function(e) {
  mapa.svg(mapLoad.responseText);
}
```

---

Then I create some paths in the SVG

```
var plane = mapa.path('...');
```

---

And this is the actual result

### [image: That's the result I'm getting]

What I want is to add all those paths inside the "#content" group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new mapa is an element within your markup, not the root element, so just [use that element](https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/referencing-creating-elements/) when you create new content.

```
var mapa = SVG('map').size('100%', '100%');

var mapLoad = new XMLHttpRequest();
mapLoad.open('GET', 'img/my_map.svg', true);
mapLoad.send();
mapLoad.onload = function(e) {
  mapa.svg(mapLoad.responseText);
  mapa = SVG.get('mapa');
  var plane = mapa.path('...');
}
```